# Implement single sign on(saml2) Azure AD(Enterprise Application) with Reactjs .NET Core Application

Tags: c#, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I want to implement single sign on(SSO) SAML2 Azure AD with React APP with .NET Core backend API.

I have already integrated Azure AD SSO(Enterprise Application) SAML 2.0 with .NET CORE Web app as below

**Azure AD Enterprise Application SSO Configuration- SAML 2.0**

[image: Azure AD Enterprise Application SSO Configuration- SAML 2.0]

And have mentioned the configuration details in the startup class as below

**Startup class**

[image: Startup class]

Everything works find and user will be authenticated using Microsoft login.

But My requirement is to integrate this Azure AD Enterprise Application SAML configuration with the React App which having a backend API.

I have already configured and tested Azure AD App Registration authentication with React front end with "react-adal" as below.

**Azure Ad app with OpenID and AUTH**

[image: Azure Ad app with OpenID and AUTH]

But for Azure AD Enterprise Application configuration With React,

Identifier (Entity ID) :

Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL) :

App Federation Metadata Url :

I don't know how to configure these things in front end.Pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

***To get the Azure Ad access token configure the frontend and make use of the token in the backend.***

You can refer this [**blog**](https://lng-consultancy.com/software-development/azure-ad-saml/) for sample codes to achieve your scenario.

After the configuration file is completed, ensure to execute the below function:

```js
import { runWithAdal } from 'react-adal';
import { authContext } from './adalConfig';
const DO_NOT_LOGIN = false;
runWithAdal(
authContext,
() => { require('./indexApp'); },
DO_NOT_LOGIN
);
```

With the above function, the user can connect with their credentials.

Make use of the **`getToken()`** method to get the authentication token that gives user access to backend.

```js
const  headers  =  {  Authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}`  };
```

**`react-adal`** library will refresh the token at least 5 minutes before the current token expiration date by default.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[A memo on how to implement Azure AD authentication using React and .NET Core | by David Bottiau | ITNEXT](https://itnext.io/a-memo-on-how-to-implement-azure-ad-authentication-using-react-and-net-core-2-0-3fe9bfdf9f36)

[How do I integrate Azure AD SSO authentication with ReactJS web application? - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/3593/how-do-i-integrate-azure-ad-sso-authentication-wit.html)